# How to get the value from this text?

Tags: regex

```
<option value="">-- Select Make --</option><option value="Acura" >Acura</option><option value="Audi" >Audi</option><option value="BMW" >BMW</option><option value="Buick" >Buick</option><option value="Cadillac" >Cadillac</option>
```

I need to get the values only from this text and I tried expression

```
value="([Aa-Zz])";
```

but it did not work what is the correct syntax ?

Comment: You should use an html Parser not regex

Comment: Add a plus after the character class and regroup the letters: `([A-Za-z]+)`

Comment: `value="(\w*)"` works. https://regex101.com/r/9Nse8r/1

Comment: Website like regex101 if you want to learn how to regex by trying. Search for some "Regex Cheat Sheet" and you should be good to go. I know the "manual" of regex could be hard to find.

Comment: Both `([A-Za-z]+)` and `\w*` work good thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`([A-Za-z]+)` and `\w*` won't take the values with spaces or special symbols inside. The first one - with digits inside, too. Use this one:

```
"[^"]*"
```

Quotes, that contain anything except quotes.

[tests](http://%22[%5E%22]*%22)